# In KVM is there an equivalent to WarpDrivePercentage

Tags: virtualbox, kvm-virtualization

VirtualBox has a little know feature called WarpDrivePercentage. This allows you to run the VM at faster or slower speeds (with some caveats). We have a test environment that simulates Set Top Boxes in KVM and a feature like this could potentially allow us to execute many more tests.

Answer (score 1):

**Hard Solution:**

I don't see a built-in option in KVM docs, but you can mess with system time. First, check what clock your KVM install is using:

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/current_clocksource
```

It's most likely `kvm-clock`. If so, you have a few options. `kvm-clock` live updates its time using the following structure:

```
struct pvclock_vcpu_time_info {
   u32   version;
   u32   pad0;
   u64   tsc_timestamp;
   u64   system_time;
   u32   tsc_to_system_mul;
   s8    tsc_shift;
   u8    flags;
   u8    pad[1];
} __attribute__((__packed__));
```

You could write a wrapper on the host to intercept this and output a sped-up version of time. You could also rebuild `kvm-clock` yourself, replacing `pvclock_vcpu_time_info` with custom logic to output UTC time with added time delta like how `libvirt` does in its [offset variable](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Virtualization_Administration_Guide/sect-Virtualization-Tips_and_tricks-Libvirt_Managed_Timers.html) `<clock offset="variable" adjustment="123456" />`

**Easier Solution:**

Continue using `virtualbox`. Or `xen` has a [comparable option](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26996_01/E18549/html/CHDJEIJI.html) of `"xen.independent_wallclock = 1"` where you can set up your own time.

**Easiest Solution:**

Ask why you need to speed up time like this? I can't think of a ton of reasons a Set Top box would need this. And it would most likely be easier to handle in your code with a fake time wrapper than at the OS level. You mess up NTP, logs, and a ton of other stuff by messing with time.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The easier solution of using VirtualBox is something I am investigating, the current system uses KVM so it will be a conversion of about 20 UCS servers. This will be useful to us as all of the tests are written to work for hardware but are mostly run on VM STBs for scalability. Many tests do not require external interfaces so "should" be able to be accelerated so long as timers and events fire at the correct times relatively. The UCS are under utiliesed with normal virtual STB execution and this is one way we are looking at of getting more from them.